# Can not click on element via TestComplete object mapping

Tags: selenium, testcomplete

I need to click on a web element, within TestComplete, this element looks like this:

[image]

I outlined its boundary using heavy-black line.

The problem is, by default, an element is always clicked in its middle point, and for this element above, clicking its middle point produces no results as it does not click this plus sign.

Within TestComplete, this element can not be broken further down into smaller elements.

I can use Selenium in JavaScript to click it, but is there is an other way?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share HTML for this element as well?? Tried attempt?? And also share if there any exception..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using x and y coordinates with the Click method.
[SmartBear Click Action](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/84863/?q=.click#_ga=1.99055132.381866387.1476215325)

I needed to click a button on my website but TestComplete was only able to identify the parent object which had 3 buttons in it.  I was able to use x,y coordinates to press the 3 different buttons in parent object.

Record a script where you click the button and look at the function created to get the coordinates you need.